# How to create outline tile texture for odd shape

Tags: texturing

[image: how I can create a tile texture that outlines an odd shape]

Hi everyone, would anyone know how I can create a tile texture that outlines an odd shape. I know how to use the Brick Node to make a normal mosaic tile like texture. But I need a row of tiles that surrounds an odd shape (not just a star) creating an outline. Hope the image I have attached is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Great illustration. Keep in mind tho, any text in an image cannot be searched for.  Font size in an image can be an issue too.  If you could edit question and include text that would be great.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info